# How to make ipcal take list of ip address in cidr

Tags: bash, grep, ip, pipe, netmask

i am able to make ipcal to give me the NETMASK using the code below.how can i make it take a list of ip address in cidr notation like 41.80.0.0/17 and give me only the ip address of netmask.if i pipe a list of ip addresses(in cidr formart) will it work. thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter IP address in CIDR notation: (eg. 192.168.0.0/24) "
read IP_ADDRESS

# Calculate network values
BROADCAST=$(ipcalc -b $IP_ADDRESS)
NETWORK=$(ipcalc -n $IP_ADDRESS)
NETMASK=$(ipcalc -m $IP_ADDRESS)

echo "Set up your ifcfg file with the following values:"
echo $BROADCAST
echo $NETWORK
echo $NETMASK
```

Comment: So `/24` should give `255.255.255.0` and `/16` give `255.255.0.0` etc?

Comment: yes. exactly. i wonder if there a way to pipe the text file with ip address with cidr notation

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do get from  `ipcalc -b 192.168.0.0/23`

```
Address:   192.168.0.0
Netmask:   255.255.254.0 = 23
Wildcard:  0.0.1.255
=>
Network:   192.168.0.0/23
HostMin:   192.168.0.1
HostMax:   192.168.1.254
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255
Hosts/Net: 510                   Class C, Private Internet
```

So to get what you need change to:

```
BROADCAST=$(ipcalc -b 192.168.0.0/23 | awk '/Broadcast/ {print $2}')
NETWORK=$(ipcalc -b 192.168.0.0/23 | awk '/Network/ {print $2}')
NETMASK=$(ipcalc -b 192.168.0.0/23 | awk '/Netmask/ {print $2}')
```

```
echo $BROADCAST
192.168.1.255
```

```
echo $NETWORK
192.168.0.0/23
```

```
echo $NETMASK
255.255.254.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script can be much simplified if you do all the processing in Awk.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter IP address in CIDR notation: (eg. 192.168.0.0/24) " IP_ADDRESS

ipcalc -b "$IP_ADDRESS" |
awk '/^Broadcast: / { b=$2 }
     /^Network: / { n=$2 }
     /^Netmask: / { m=$2 }
     END { print "Set up your ifcfg file with the following values:";
       print b; print n; print m; }'
```